# Giving an app permissions to my documents folder without admin

Tags: macos, permission, system-settings

I have macOS Catalina and I wanted to see if there was a way for me to change the setting where you give apps access to files/folders. I have a game that wants access to documents and it isn't giving me the option to grant it. When I go to settings, the plus sign isn't clickable and I don't have administrator privileges so I can't turn it on. All I want to do is give it access to my Documents folder. This wasn't a problem until I updated to 10.15 and apps started prompting me to give them permissions, but this one never gave me a prompt. I was thinking maybe I could change it in the file where the mac keeps its preferences or if there is some command in terminal or maybe I'm just being an idiot and I can do it in System Preferences.

Thanks

Comment: The exact error it threw was:"Script 'Interpreter 7' line 279: Errno::EPERM occured. Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /Users/aguilard/Documents/Oneshot/README.txt"

Comment: If you don‘t have admin access, what hinders you from asking the person who has?

Comment: It's a computer that my school gave me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to make the change from the command line if you can’t make it from the GUI.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/control-access-files-folders-mac-mchld5a35146/mac

Look in settings for Profiles - if you see them, the people managing settings will need to grant your app permissions or let you become an admin or make the allowance for you.

Comment: Thanks I already fixed the problem by first making sure that was the problem so in the script that runs the program I put a line of code that created a file there and it worked and then I found out it was that there was a file there named README already and it couldn't overwrite it